# spoofing time on server

Tags: php, html

I have a web page that receives currently playing songs on my local radio stations. It gets song data from Radiotime.com. My problem is that the server that hosts my page is in the American Central time zone, and as such, the times in the data received by the server are in Central time. The radio stations and I, however, are in the Eastern time zone, so I would prefer the times shown on my web page to be in Eastern time. Can I spoof the time zone shown by the server, or can I convert the times shown on the page somehow? Any help will be greatly appreciated. -Austin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.1 or greater you can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); // set timezone to Eastern
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not quite sure why though. My code is as follows: 
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

#code to receive data

Comment: @cheeseisedible: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: I am using 5.2.13

Comment: @cheese: try echoing the current time right after the call, does that appear to be the right time?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: It shows the correct time in the echo. This must mean that Radiotime.com uses IP geolocation to find out what time to display on their page, right?

Comment: @cheese: I'm not sure what radiotime.com is doing, but the experiment indicates that the issue isn't displaying time on your server. Maybe part of the radiotime API will let you specify the timezone, if not just add 3600 seconds for the central - eastern offset and be move on :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
```

or try with

```
putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");
```

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: set timezone according to your need here is [list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [supported timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) string with the [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function.

You probably want something like:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time to be different for the entire server, you could change the server's timezone. On Debian-derived distributions such as Ubuntu, you could run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to configure the timezone.

If you just want the webserver to run in a different timezone, you could set the `TZ` environment variable in the `/etc/init.d/nginx` or similar init script.

You can probably also set the `TZ` environment variable inside your specific program; most languages provide a `setenv` or similar function, that would affect the output of many time-related functions. (`gmtime(3)` of course won't care.)